# HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved

Tags: java, cloud, jstl, hana

I'm using JSTL 1.2 to populate a table from a servlet. I have included the right things in the web.xml and have imported the .jar file in the WEB-INF/lib. Also this is the only .jar file added to the folder and I'm running this on SAP HANA cloud server

web.xml:

```xml
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
```

the include in the .jsp page:

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Comment: What JSTL version do you have in your `lib` folder?

Comment: jstl 1.2.jar was added to the lib folder. Sorry I forgot to add that in my q

Comment: 1) Which Servlet container or Application Server are you running this and 2) List all your jar files found in `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Comment: @user1523627, we need the **exact** name of the jar files listed. This can help us identify if you're just running a JSTL API jar or JSTL-IMPL jar or both.

Comment: @Buhake Sindi I'm sorry. kinda of a noob. The exact name of the jar file i downloaded and used is "jstl-1.2.jar"

Comment: @user1523627. Apart from that are you having any other JAR files?

Comment: Also, is your project Mavenized?

Comment: I have no idea what a Mavenized project is

Comment: @user1523627 The only possibility I can see here is you are including the older JSTL API somehow in your build path. If you have set your targeted runtime, check the `lib` of that runtime, whether it holds some conflicting JAR, like - `standard.jar`?

Comment: @Rohit Jain All I have is a md5 jar and even without it I still get the same error